# Adding keys from dict to columns headers in an existing Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dataframe ('DF1') and I have a dict ('dictdf').
I want to add columns headers based on the dict, those columns needs to be empty.

DF1:

```
ID  age

12   33
23   55
67   12
```

result:

```
ID  age  height  eye_color  ....  

12   33    NA      NA       ....
23   55    NA      NA       ....
67   12    NA      NA       ....
```

This is what I tried:

```
colNames = DF1.columns
for key in dictdf.keys():
    colNames.append(key)

newDF = pd.DataFrame(DF1,columns=colNames)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: all inputs must be Index
```

Any idea on a simple solution? I don't want to start transforming from dict to DF or the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with an empty dataframe with defined columns. As a single operation, this will be more efficient than manual appending columns in a loop.

```
d = {'height': 120, 'eye_color': 'brown'}

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(columns=d))

print(df)

   ID  age height eye_color
0  12   33    NaN       NaN
1  23   55    NaN       NaN
2  67   12    NaN       NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.append.html) for all cols with [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
d = {'height': 120, 'eye_color': 'brown'}

df = df.reindex(columns=df.columns.append(pd.Index(d)))
print (df)
   ID  age  height  eye_color
0  12   33     NaN        NaN
1  23   55     NaN        NaN
2  67   12     NaN        NaN
```